# SmartWatch 2: require a static function to get my Widget object

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I create a widget (extends from BaseWidget) by using Sony Add-on SDK v3 for SmartWatch 2 and am implementing a function to update the widget content when user changes widget related options on phone.

That means that I need a function to get my Widget object so I can call BaseWidget.showLayout() function from my Android app.

Would Sony SmartWatch team add a static function likes below?

```
/**
 * return a Widget object if user places it on the watch face
 * wo: widget class
 */
public static BaseWidget
BaseWidget.getWidget(Class<? extends BaseWidget> wo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your wigit with a static class, e.g. a singleton on create. Then the rest of the system can get access to it from there.

You could unregister it on destroy.

Comment: I checked the lifetime cycle of SmartWatch 2's BaseWidget and found that the onCreate() function won't be called when system re-create the app process. So your suggestion won't work when the app process has been killed by system (due to low memory or new version replaced).

Comment: In that case is the same wigit. And the destroy hasn't been called. So it will still be registered.